# What can be a reason of dark areas on mesh?

Tags: topology, artifacts

I worked in edit and sculpt modes and clicked some key combination. After that I've got strange dark areas at mesh:
[image]

What could be a reason of this areas? I haven't changed anything in shader, so the problem should be related to topology, but I don't know any function which can do this.

File: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the split normals (normals that determine the shading) are messed up, go into the *Data panel > Geometry Data and click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you!